# How does this function work in javascript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I need your help in understanding below codes.

```
map<U>(mapFunction: (task: Task, index: number)=> U) {
        return this.tasks.map(mapFunction);
}

forEach<U>(mapFunction: (task: Task, index: number)=> U) {
        return this.tasks.forEach(mapFunction);
 }
```

Can anyone explain me how these codes work. I'm trying to search it but failed. I know there is a term for using these codes. I just don't get the term

Comment: You wish to know how `forEach` function is implemented in reactJs/js, how `mapFunction` is implemented ow that?

Comment: was this reactjs code ? and you wanted to know the vanilla javascript counter part of it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is at least some information if not all.

[Link to explanation](https://www.discovermeteor.com/blog/understanding-javascript-map/)

It's called a

> javascript map function

In short:
It itererates over array elements and calling functions on them

Answer (score 1):

It's nothing but fat arrow in type script. this gets convert to java script using transpilers and Babel is one of the popular for this job

[more information on fat arrow](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html)